# Как реализовать переходы между фреймами?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

Имеется небольшая тестовая программа, по своей сути набросок будущего опросника, основанная на фреймах. В тестовом варианте три фрейма, кнопки длаее и назад.
По задумке это должно работать так: каждый фрейм будет включать в себя вопрос (в виде label-метки с текстом) и ответ (в виде combobox с вариантами ответов). Пользователь выбирает вариант ответа -> нажимает кнопку далее -> в зависимости от варианта ответа появляется нужный фрейм. Соответственно при нажатии на кнопку назад происходит откат к фрейму с вопросом, с которого пользователь перешел на вопрос от которого откатывается назад.

В том варианте, который я сюда выложил, при выборе во фрейме 0 (value_0_frame) варианта ответа 1, появляется фрейм 1 (value_1_frame), соответственно, при выборе во фрейме 0 (value_0_frame) варианта ответа 2, появляется фрейм (value_2_frame). Ну и кнопка назад должна откатывать пользователя к фрейму 0. Вроде бы звучит не сложно и у меня получилось сделать движение вперед, но, как сделать движение в обратную сторону не понимаю.

Собственно весь вопрос как сделать механизм отката на предыдущий фрейм?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, RIGHT, BOTH, GROOVE, FLAT
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style

app = tk.Tk()
width = 800
height = 600
x = int((app.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (width / 2))
y = int((app.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (height / 2))
app.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

mine_frame = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
mine_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=88, pady=100)

def fwd_frame():
    value_0 = slt_value_0.get()
    if value_0 == '1':
        value_1()
    if value_0 == '2':
        value_2()

def value_1():
    value_0_frame.forget()
    value_2_frame.forget()

def value_2():
    value_1_frame.forget()
    value_0_frame.forget()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 0
value_0_frame = Frame(mine_frame, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
value_0_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=200, pady=150)
lbl_value_0 = tk.Label(value_0_frame, text='Select value 1:', font=('Tahoma', 8), justify='left',
                    foreground='#ffffff', background='#5050A1')
lbl_value_0.pack(padx=2, pady=10)
slt_value_0 = ttk.Combobox(value_0_frame, values=['1', '2'])
slt_value_0.pack(padx=2, pady=10)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 1
value_1_frame = Frame(mine_frame, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
value_1_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=200, pady=150)
lbl_value_1 = tk.Label(value_1_frame, text='Select value 2:', font=('Tahoma', 8), justify='left',
                    foreground='#ffffff', background='#5050A1')
lbl_value_1.pack(padx=2, pady=10)
slt_value_1 = ttk.Combobox(value_1_frame, values=['2', '3'])
slt_value_1.pack(padx=2, pady=10)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 2
value_2_frame = Frame(mine_frame, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
value_2_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=200, pady=150)
lbl_value_2 = tk.Label(value_2_frame, text='Select value 3:', font=('Tahoma', 8), justify='left',
                    foreground='#ffffff', background='#5050A1')
lbl_value_2.pack(padx=2, pady=10)
slt_value_2 = ttk.Combobox(value_2_frame, values=['3', '4'])
slt_value_2.pack(padx=2, pady=10)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------BUTTONS
btn_01 = ttk.Button(app, text='>', command=fwd_frame)
btn_01.place(x=710, y=299, height=401, width=80, anchor='w')

btn_02 = ttk.Button(app, text='<')
btn_02.place(x=10, y=299, height=401, width=80, anchor='w')

app.mainloop()
```

Заранее большое спасибо за уделенное внимание, буду рад любым подсказкам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ночи! Не смотря подсказки eri, со словарями у меня не срослось, пришлось сделать более топорно, но, главное, работает как нужно:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import BOTH, GROOVE, FLAT, DISABLED
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Frame

app = tk.Tk()
width = 400
height = 200
x = int((app.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (width / 2))
y = int((app.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (height / 2))
app.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 0
def vl_0():
    btn_start.destroy()

    mine_frame_0 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_0.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_0():
        value_0 = slt_value_0.get()
        if value_0 == '1':
            mine_frame_0.forget()
            vl_1()
        if value_0 == '2':
            mine_frame_0.forget()
            vl_2()

    btn_fwd_0 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_0, text='>', command=fwd_0)
    btn_fwd_0.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    btn_bwd_0 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_0, text='<', state=DISABLED)
    btn_bwd_0.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_0_frame = Frame(mine_frame_0, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_0_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_0 = tk.Label(value_0_frame, text='Native value:')
    lbl_value_0.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_0 = ttk.Combobox(value_0_frame, values=['1', '2'])
    slt_value_0.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 1
def vl_1():
    mine_frame_1 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_1():
        value_1 = slt_value_1.get()
        if value_1 == '3':
            mine_frame_1.forget()
            vl_3()
        if value_1 == '4':
            mine_frame_1.forget()
            vl_4()

    btn_fwd_1 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_1, text='>', command=fwd_1)
    btn_fwd_1.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    def bwd_1():
        mine_frame_1.forget()
        vl_0()

    btn_bwd_1 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_1, text='<', command=bwd_1)
    btn_bwd_1.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_1_frame = Frame(mine_frame_1, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_1_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_1 = tk.Label(value_1_frame, text='Value 1:')
    lbl_value_1.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_1 = ttk.Combobox(value_1_frame, values=['3', '4'])
    slt_value_1.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 2
def vl_2():
    mine_frame_2 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_2():
        value_2 = slt_value_2.get()
        if value_2 == '5':
            mine_frame_2.forget()
            vl_5()
        if value_2 == '6':
            mine_frame_2.forget()
            vl_6()

    btn_fwd_2 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_2, text='>', command=fwd_2)
    btn_fwd_2.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    def bwd_2():
        mine_frame_2.forget()
        vl_0()

    btn_bwd_2 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_2, text='<', command=bwd_2)
    btn_bwd_2.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_2_frame = Frame(mine_frame_2, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_2_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_2 = tk.Label(value_2_frame, text='Value 2:')
    lbl_value_2.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_2 = ttk.Combobox(value_2_frame, values=['5', '6'])
    slt_value_2.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 3
def vl_3():
    mine_frame_3 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_3.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_3():
        value_3 = slt_value_3.get()
        if value_3 == '7':
            pass
        if value_3 == '8':
            pass

    btn_fwd_3 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_3, text='>', command=fwd_3)
    btn_fwd_3.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    def bwd_3():
        mine_frame_3.forget()
        vl_1()

    btn_bwd_3 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_3, text='<', command=bwd_3)
    btn_bwd_3.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_3_frame = Frame(mine_frame_3, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_3_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_3 = tk.Label(value_3_frame, text='Value 3:')
    lbl_value_3.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_3 = ttk.Combobox(value_3_frame, values=['7', '8'])
    slt_value_3.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 4
def vl_4():
    mine_frame_4 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_4.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_4():
        value_4 = slt_value_4.get()
        if value_4 == '9':
            pass
        if value_4 == '10':
            pass

    btn_fwd_4 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_4, text='>', command=fwd_4)
    btn_fwd_4.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    def bwd_4():
        mine_frame_4.forget()
        vl_1()

    btn_bwd_4 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_4, text='<', command=bwd_4)
    btn_bwd_4.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_4_frame = Frame(mine_frame_4, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_4_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_4 = tk.Label(value_4_frame, text='Value 4:')
    lbl_value_4.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_4 = ttk.Combobox(value_4_frame, values=['9', '10'])
    slt_value_4.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 5
def vl_5():
    mine_frame_5 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_5.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_5():
        value_5 = slt_value_5.get()
        if value_5 == '9':
            pass
        if value_5 == '10':
            pass

    btn_fwd_5 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_5, text='>', command=fwd_5)
    btn_fwd_5.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    def bwd_5():
        mine_frame_5.forget()
        vl_2()

    btn_bwd_5 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_5, text='<', command=bwd_5)
    btn_bwd_5.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_5_frame = Frame(mine_frame_5, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_5_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_5 = tk.Label(value_5_frame, text='Value 5:')
    lbl_value_5.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_5 = ttk.Combobox(value_5_frame, values=['11', '12'])
    slt_value_5.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------FRAME 6
def vl_6():
    mine_frame_6 = Frame(app, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=1)
    mine_frame_6.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=1)

    def fwd_6():
        value_6 = slt_value_6.get()
        if value_6 == '13':
            pass
        if value_6 == '14':
            pass

    btn_fwd_6 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_6, text='>', command=fwd_6)
    btn_fwd_6.pack(fill='y', side='right')

    def bwd_6():
        mine_frame_6.forget()
        vl_2()

    btn_bwd_6 = ttk.Button(mine_frame_6, text='<', command=bwd_6)
    btn_bwd_6.pack(fill='y', side='left')

    value_6_frame = Frame(mine_frame_6, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
    value_6_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=1, pady=60)
    lbl_value_6 = tk.Label(value_6_frame, text='Value 6:')
    lbl_value_6.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
    slt_value_6 = ttk.Combobox(value_6_frame, values=['13', '14'])
    slt_value_6.pack(padx=1, pady=1)


btn_start = ttk.Button(app, text='START', command=vl_0)
btn_start.pack(expand=True, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

app.mainloop()
```

Спасибо eri за отклик и попытку помочь. Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1):

Положите фреймы в словарь value_1_frame -> frames['1']

Скрытие будет проще:

```
def showframe(value):

    # скрыть все
    for k,v in frames.items():
        v.forget()

    # или чуть поаккуратней если pack будет только в этой функции
    frames[history[-1]].forget()
```

Потом сделйте список куда добавляется фрейм при переключении на него.

```
    # отобразить нужный
    history.append(value)
    frames[value].pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=200, pady=150)
```

*Кстати forget это обратное действие к pack*

Идти назад:

```
history.pop()
showframe(history[-1])
```

Если нужно идти вперед по старым ответам, то вместо pop/-1 используйте число в переменной. Но придется ещё реализовать срез истории  при выборе другого ответа

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, попробую и отпишусь. Насчет среза истории, я попробую сначала без заморочек, если получится, тогда можно будет и усложнять.

Comment: Ковырялся, ковырялся... в результате, словарь сделал. Куда девать все остальное не понимаю: 
def showframe(value) - что есть тут value?
"список куда добавляется фрейм при переключении на него" - это, если я правильно понимаю, нужно еще один словарь сделать?
С движением вперед оставлю как есть, работает и хорошо.

Comment: value в вашем коде slt_value_0.get() но туда просто передаешь ключ словаря какой фрейм открыть